# Is it right to have puppies locked?

Tags: dogs, health, safety

We found 4 orphaned puppies which are 1-2 month old. We built a small home for them with water inside it. 
During the time 9 pm- 7 am, no one can keep an eye on them and they wander around so we closed the entry.

Is this okay? Will it be harmful? What else can we do? If they wander around, they will get lost or killed.

I am in India.

Comment: Contact a local vet or shelter. Depending on their age it might be better to temporarily give them a surrogate mother even if it's just for socializing etc.

Comment: @Mario most areas of the world, have internet.  Not all areas have animal protection organizations (shelters).

Comment: @Mario sir we have very less animal shelters in india. There is one in my city very far away but all they can do is put them up for adoption on their facebook page.

Comment: After reading your comments, is it possible to get them neutered and spayed? I know it costs much, but it would be a good investment for the future.

Answer (score 2):

As long as they stay in their small eclosure only at night they should be fine. Just realize that, depending on the breed, they will likely outgrow their enclosure pretty fast.

My suggestion would be to find loving homes you can place them into as fast as you can as I doubt that you would want to keep 4 dogs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sir/mam in india there are stray dogs everywhere. 30 Million of them. No one adopts them. My family doesnt allow me either. We are just trying to help them grow and then they can be quite dependent, thank you

Comment: @RamKeswani, you seem pretty adamant that these dogs will not find a home.  What's your long term plan?  Think about the future as well as what you are doing to help them now.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I just found that the animal shelter is organising a puppy adoption program. All I can hope now is that all of them get adopted.

Comment: This is hard, but with so many dogs running around adding 4 more just makes the situation worse. Spaying and neutering costs a lot even here in the US much less in India. Hopefuly the shelter will do that before they adopt the pupies out. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

It may at least be more safe than the puppies wandering about alone. As you said you don't have an animal-shelter in your area, does anyone near you have a dog, perhaps even one who's had puppies before, or currently has any? If yes, bringing them together may be good for the socialisation of the puppies.
If you can, also offer at least dry food over the day. Usually, I would say wet food would be better for the puppies, but from the impression I get, rodents and insects being drawn might be an issue if you leave out wet food. Dry food should cause less trouble in that area.
And, yes, I agree with user508439: find them a home as soon as you can, they NEED social contact and someone to teach them how to behave.
Best wishes to you and the puppies!

Comment: Sir/mam no one adopts them in india. Everyone says Indian pariah breed is dirty and bad and all of that. They prefer buying a labrador, golden retriever over a free needy stray puppy. I will surely open an animal shelter soon. India is a hell for animals.